# Table is not creating in mail body

Tags: php, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to send user input to mail in tabular form, user input is passing to mail but I'm unable create table there. So far what I have did is:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control fc" name="patient" id="Patient">
<input type="date" class="form-control fc" name = "date" id="Date">
<input type="text" class="form-control fc" name = "Assistant" id="Assistant">
```

PHP part

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email_to = "xyz@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Data";
$patient = $_POST['patient'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$Assistant = $_POST['Assistant'];


$email_message ="<html><body>";
$email_message .= "<table><tr><td>Field Name : </td><td>Value</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td>Patient Name : </td><td>".$patient."</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td>Date:</td><td> ".$date."</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td>Assistant:</td><td> ".$Assistant."</td></tr></table>";
$email_message .="</body></html>";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.xyz@gmail.com."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.xyz@gmail.com."\r\n" .
'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to send html mail you must set the headers:

```
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
```

see the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

use PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->isHTML(TRUE);
$mailer->Host = 'smtp host';
$mailer->Port = 'smtp post';
....
$mailer->body = "put your html here"
$mailer->send();
```